# v9 metadata webapi - create solution

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Receive the following error when trying to create a solution via the webapi v9:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"0x0","message":"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node
> with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'publisherid'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue'
> node with null value was expected.\r\n   at

I have tried a json object in the field as well, but nothing works for setting the publisherid.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I forgot it has to be in the format:

```
"publisherid@odata.bind": "https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/publishers(60f77a42-5f0e-e611-80e0-00155da84c03)"
```